# Understanding Associations in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to understand associations in Sequelize. I'm starting from existing database tables so some of the fields may not match up to the defaults in Sequelize. I've used Sequelizer to generate my models directly from the database. 
I'm accustomed to writing queries but now I'm trying to learn how an ORM like Sequelize works.

Here's my models.

**models/user.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        field: "id"
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
        field: "username"
      },
      fullname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false,
        field: "fullname"
      },
      createdat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: "createdat"
      },
      updateat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: "updateat"
      },
      deletedat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: "deletedat"
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: "users",
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

  User.associate = function(models) {
        models.User.hasMany(models.Ticket),
        { as: "createdbyname", foreignKey: "createdby" };
  };
  return User;
};
```

**models/ticket.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Ticket = sequelize.define(
    "Ticket",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        field: "id"
      },
      details: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "details"
      },
      assignedto: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "assignedto"
      },
      createdby: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "createdby"
      },
      createdat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: "createdat"
      },
      updatedat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: "updatedat"
      },
      deletedat: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: "deletedat"
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: "tickets",
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

  Ticket.associate = function(models) {
        models.Ticket.belongsTo(models.User,
            { foreignKey: "createdby" });
  };
  return Ticket;
};
```

In my route handler, I'm calling User.findAll as follows:

```
  models.User.findAll({
    include: [models.Ticket]
  })
```

The result I expect to see is a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`id`,
    `User`.`username`,
    `User`.`fullname`,
    `User`.`createdat`,
    `User`.`updateat`,
    `User`.`deletedat`,
    `Tickets`.`id` AS `Tickets.id`,
    `Tickets`.`details` AS `Tickets.details`,
    `Tickets`.`assignedto` AS `Tickets.assignedto`,
    `Tickets`.`createdby` AS `Tickets.createdby`,
    `Tickets`.`createdat` AS `Tickets.createdat`,
    `Tickets`.`updatedat` AS `Tickets.updatedat`,
    `Tickets`.`deletedat` AS `Tickets.deletedat`
FROM
    `users` AS `User`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `tickets` AS `Tickets` ON `User`.`id` = `Tickets`.`createdby`
```

The query I see running in the console is:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`id`,
    `User`.`username`,
    `User`.`fullname`,
    `User`.`createdat`,
    `User`.`updateat`,
    `User`.`deletedat`,
    `Tickets`.`id` AS `Tickets.id`,
    `Tickets`.`details` AS `Tickets.details`,
    `Tickets`.`assignedto` AS `Tickets.assignedto`,
    `Tickets`.`createdby` AS `Tickets.createdby`,
    `Tickets`.`createdat` AS `Tickets.createdat`,
    `Tickets`.`updatedat` AS `Tickets.updatedat`,
    `Tickets`.`deletedat` AS `Tickets.deletedat`,
    `Tickets`.`UserId` AS `Tickets.UserId`
FROM
    `users` AS `User`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `tickets` AS `Tickets` ON `User`.`id` = `Tickets`.`UserId`;
```

Note difference in LEFT OUTER JOIN clause. This is throwing an error as follows:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Tickets.UserId' in 'field list'
```

I need some help figuring out where I've gone wrong here.

Comment: I found this thread useful for same reasons of brilang i order to point me in the right direction to define the associations in modles. Next step is how to populate the relations. I am reading documentation about setUser or addUser but none is working. Help or sugestions will be apreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining associations, like `belongsTo`, you can specify a `foreignKey` and a `targetKey`. The `foreignKey` corresponds to the field in the source table (remember, the syntax is `sourceModel.belongsTo(targetModel, options)`). The `targetKey` corresponds to the field in the target table.

In your case, you made a mistake in the association in the **models/ticket.js** file, you used:

```
models.Ticket.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "createdby" });
```

Here, `foreignKey` references the source table, Ticket. Therefore, your are telling Sequelize to use the field `createdBy` for the `Ticket` table, and the default (the primary key) for the `User` table. As `createdBy` does not exists within `Ticket`, Sequelize falls back to the default case, where it uses `Ticket.UserID`.

To fix your association (and query), you need to update your `belongsTo` to the following:

```
models.Ticket.belongsTo(models.User, { targetKey: "createdby" });
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this sample working. I've moved on to other libraries as I'm experimenting and learning what works and doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  Plant.findAll({
        include: Farm,
        order: [['name', 'ASC']]
        })
        .then(data=> {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send(err)
            console.log(err);
            
        })
        
let arrQuery = [
      queryInterface.addColumn('farms', 'dayPlayed' , Sequelize.STRING),
      queryInterface.removeColumn('plants', 'dayPlayed' , Sequelize.STRING),
    ]
      return Promise.all(arrQuery)
```

Comment: Some text explanation would be helpful, especially since running the snippet yields an error